# Devise - Same Model - Different pages & routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two different kinds of users in my system. Trying to setup two different sets of devise pages / controllers for them.

I can understand how this can be done when there are multiple models. But wondering how this can be done with the same model?

eg.

`/seller/sign_in`

and

`/buyer/sign_in`

Answer (score 1):

**Use device_scope to change default route**

****Assuming you have **user** device model

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get "/seller/sign_in", to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get "/buyer/sign_in", to: 'devise/sessions#new'
  end
```

Comment: plus, unless he wants different login windows for different roles 